# Laravel import Excel how to select a sheet from excel file and import it to database table

Tags: laravel-5, import-from-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to import an excel file to my database using [Laravel excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) package.
the file contains many sheets, I want to import every sheet to a different table in the database.
I have tried the following code but I couldn't find any result.

```
$file = Input::file('file');
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        Excel::selectSheets('Branches')->load($file, function($reader){
            $reader->each(function($sheet){
                foreach($sheet->toArray() as $row){
                    Branch::firstOrCreate($row=$sheet->toArray());
                    echo'done';
                    dd($row);
                }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying, searching and going through [Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) documentation, I found that I have to load the whole Excel file and inside this process I can use the sheets selection methods which is given by the package.

Example:

```
foreach($getSheetName as $sheetName)
{
    if ($sheetName === 'Branches')
    {
         Excel::selectSheets($sheetName)->load($request->file('file'), function ($reader)
         {
                foreach($reader->toArray() as $sheet)
                {
                      Branch::create($sheet);
                }
         });
    }
}
```